# dnsmasq resolve all domains to same address except www.google.com

Tags: dnsmasq

I need dnsmasq resolves all domains to `10.10.128.1` except `www.google.com`, but  `address=/#/10.10.128.1` 
will resolves all domains, how should I add some rules for `www.google.com`?

Answer (score -1):

Just write the google directive before:

address=/google.com/10.10.128.100

address=/#/10.10.128.1

;)

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things. Also add more details.